# Symmetric and self-adjoint unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

I'm using the definitions here: [Distinguishing between symmetric, Hermitian and self-adjoint operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38387/distinguishing-between-symmetric-hermitian-and-self-adjoint-operators).

Let $\mathcal{D}(D) = \{ (x_n)_n \in \ell^2 : \sum_{n} n^2|x_n|^2 < \infty \}$.

Let $D: \mathcal{D}(D) \rightarrow \ell^2$ be the diagonal operator $De_n=ne_n$.

Show is symmetric. Is $D$ self-adjoint?

My attempt:

To show it's symmetric, we want to show that $\langle x, Dy \rangle = \langle Dx, y \rangle$.

We have $\langle D^* e_n, e_m \rangle = \langle e_n, De_m \rangle = \langle e_n, n e_m \rangle = \bar{n} \delta_{mn} = n \delta{mn}$.

Now the definitions are messing me up.. I'm not sure if I'm proving that it's symmetric or self-adjoint...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is where you are testing your operator.

To see that an operator is symmetric, you proceed as you did and show that given two generic elements **of your domain** $x,\ y\in\mathcal D\left(D\right)$ you have that $ \langle x, Dy\rangle= \langle Dx,y\rangle $ (with the same $ D $!).

On the other hand, the concept of self-adjoint goes hand in hand with the concept of adjoint; if you have that $ D^* $ is the adjoint of $ D $, then self-adjoint means only that as operators $ D $ and $ D^* $ coincide, i.e., their domains are equal and the action on the domains are equal.

So we are reduced to understand what the adjoint of an operator $ D $ is. To do so, you first assume that your operator $ D $ is densily defined (which is your case) and define the domain
$$
\mathcal D\left(D^*\right):=\left\{x\in\ell^2|\ \exists C\mbox{ s.t. }\left|\langle x,Dy\rangle\right|\le C\left\|y\right\| \forall y\in \mathcal D\left(D\right)\right\}.
$$

Then, for any element in $ \mathcal D\left(D^*\right) $ the mapping $ y\mapsto\langle x,Dy\rangle $ is define on a dense of your Hilbert space $ \ell^2 $ and it is bounded, so it can be extended to an element of the dual, and therefore, via Riesz representation theorem there is a unique element of your space $ z $ such that $ \langle x,Dy\rangle=\langle z,y\rangle $ for any $ y\in\mathcal D\left(D\right) $. By definition, $ D^*x:=z $.

Getting to the exercise. As you noticed, $ \langle e_n, De_m\rangle=n\delta_{nm}=\langle De_n, e_m\rangle $, therefore, given $ x,\ y\in\ell^2 $ we have
\begin{align}
\langle x,D y\rangle
&=\langle\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}x_ne_n,D\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}y_me_m\rangle
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}x_n y_m\langle e_n,De_m\rangle
\\
&
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}x_n y_mm\delta_{nm}
=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sum_{m\in\mathbb N}x_n y_mn\delta_{nm}
=\langle Dx,y\rangle,
\end{align}
and $ D $ is symmetric.

Now I will show you that $ \mathcal D\left(D^*\right)=\mathcal D\left(D\right) $. The inclusion $ \supseteq $ is trivial, so let's show the other inclusion. Let $ x $ be in $ \mathcal D\left(D^*\right) $. Consider the sequence of elements $ y(k) $ of $ \mathcal D\left(D\right) $ (a sequence of sequences) defined as
$$
y(k)=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{nx_n}{\left\|\sum_{n=0}^knx_ne_n\right\|}e_n.
$$

With this definition $ \|y(k)\|=1 $ and $ y(k)\in\mathcal D\left(D\right) $ trivially, given that it is a finite sequence. Therefore we get that, given that $ x\in\mathcal D\left(D\right) $, there exists a constant $ C $ such that
\begin{align}
C=C\left\|y(k)\right\|&\ge\left|\langle x,Dy\left(k\right)\rangle\right|
=\left|\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\overline{x_n}ny(k)_n\right|
=\frac1{\left\|\sum_{n=0}^knx_ne_n\right\|}\left|\sum_{n=0}^kn^2\left|x_n\right|^2\right|
\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^kn^2\left|x_n\right|^2\right)^\frac12.
\end{align}

It follows immediately that we can send $ k $ to infinity and get that the series in the last term is convergent and $ x\in\mathcal D\left(D\right) $ and the two domains coincide.

Finally is an exercise of dialectic to prove that now the actions of $ D $ and $ D^* $ coincide on their (common) domain. Indeed let $ x,y\in\mathcal D\left(D\right)=\mathcal D\left(D^*\right) $, by definition of $ D^* $ and using the symmetry we get
\begin{align}
\langle x,D^* y\rangle
=\langle Dx,y\rangle
=\langle x,D y\rangle.
\end{align}

Given that the domain of $ D $ is dense, this implies $ D^*y=Dy $ for every y in the domain, and therefore $ D=D^* $. Hence, $ D $ is also self-adjoint.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see why $\mathcal{D}(D^*) =\mathcal{D}(D)  $ implies $D= D^*$. Could you explain a little bit more? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I edited my answer to include also this point.